# Are "Sprite-work" requests applicable to graphic design on Stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

**To Start**:
I know that Graphic Design is a Q&A Site, I very much understand that.

I only have One Problem, I'm unsure if asking something along the lines of a "sprite work" or "spriting request" is an applicable question.

I'm a newer user in the stackexchange community, and I work with making C# designs.
I wanted to work on a game, and required "Art" of a form, but I'm not prideful enough in my own work.

So is a question along those lines Acceptable in some form?

Or would a better question be along the lines of:

> What are some recommended strategies or places to get help with Sprite Work?

as more of a "recommendation" question, rather than an Abrupt Request for art.

Comment: Hi there Taylor and welcome to GDSE. It's not so much about how you phrase it. The question must be about *graphic design*, it must be *answerable* and have *relevance* to others (also in the future). So you can ask questions about how to create sprites and maybe also about how programmers and artists can work together. But if the site allowed "networking" questions it would quickly be filled with outdated noise with no relevance to others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My *opinion* is asking for someone who can do the work, or asking for a references where you can find someone to do the work, is **off-topic**.

This isn't a "job board" or a "referral service". There are *many* other sites to accommodate that need.

Although, there may be many members capable of completing such work, or who know someone who can, as soon as you allow 1 question asking for a worker or referral, you open the floodgates.

Asking **how** to complete something with respect to sprites would be totally **on-topic** however.

Comment: Perhaps the developers. or really anyone with permissions, should make a chat room for "art-work" and such, where something like sprite work requests and such things could be done. You say that many sites accommodate art work requests, but I SEVERELY had trouble finding a reliable one myself.

Comment: @TaylorSpark look being able to draw stuff is a specialized skill. Even if it does not feel like it. So at the end of the day we would wish to ge home with a paycheck for our time. If your request keeps me occupied for a day i want a days worth of money for the task. Now since you are asking for animation one day is often not enough, dealing with the client and getting paid also often adds a few days of work. For simplicity that its a week worth of work. Now you can calculate how much money that must bring in. Usually once you are willing to pay going rate you have no problems finding workers.